# How long does it take to start losing belly fat

Tags: nutrition, diet, body-fat, stomach

I jog about 30 minutes 5 days each week and was wondering how long it will take to start losing belly fat, like timewise. Is there a specific formula or something that i can use for jogging? Thanks

Comment: This question should belong to [Physical Fitness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: More information would be needed such as your diet as that has an impact on weight loss as well.

Comment: Physical fitness we would mark it as a duplicate. Body fat works on the LIFO (Last in, first out) concept. So if your belly is the first place you put on fat, it's the last place it will disappear from. It's been asked several times in various forms there. Here's one reference there: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast

Comment: @JohnP, do you have any scientific references for the last in, first out principle?  This site is for evidenced based medicine, not dogmatic principles.